# Why does it say I have two arguments?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

It says I have two arguments, don't I only have one?`[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex = %@", selection];`

Answer (score 1):

Look really closely at the line of code, especially at the "," followed by "selection". That isn't valid Objective-C.

The method is:

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

Refactoring: I think you mean (FWIW I don't know JavaScript):

```
NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex = %@", selection];
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: javaScript];
```

Breaking compound statements into separate statements can really help find errors.